# precompile assets without digest in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to precompile assets without the digest on the end?

When the assets are precompiled with digest my rails application cannot find the assets that it needs to find.

Such as

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js
```

The line I use to link the application.js is

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Is there a way to either disable the digest or have the rails application use the digest paths?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to take care of adding digest to`application.js` in `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`. During the precompilation it will automatically get converted to

```
<script src="/assets/application-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.js"></script>
```

To answer your other questions, If you are on Rails 4.x, compiling assets without digest has been removed because the version of sprockets-rails used in Rails 4.x doesn't support assets without digest.

You can refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production.

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49

Comment: So than any idea why it is not finding the files with digest on them? It is looking for the files there without digest